# What does (any) Windows do to EFI partition during an update (in general)?

Tags: windows, grub, uefi, refind

If someone has any information about Windows update actions, please share.

I'm currently running Pop!_OS 22.04 (and other several temporary distros) and booting to it through rEFInd. So, I heard a lot of comments about Windows breaking GRUB, but I don't know what that means exactly. Does it wipe EFI partition? Does it remove non-Windows stuff from EFI partition? Maybe something else?

I know for a fact that rEFInd basically have its own folder in EFI partition, and it automatically detects installed OSes and you can create custom boot entries in the same folder. This means that rEFInd is more clear than GRUB (I remember GRUB also stores some files in `/boot/` directory of a distro). But I think it doesn't solve the "Windows update broke my GRUB (rEFInd)" problem. Or does it?

As rEFInd is a standalone folder (in practice), it will be probably impossible to boot into Pop with Windows (if I had one) removing the folder of the bootloader (without recreating rEFInd via live CD).

P.S. I'm just curious about this, and I don't have any issues (because I no longer have Windows installed — and that's a huge relief).

Comment: When a system updates, Windows or grub, it normally makes itself first in UEFI boot order. Many then think it has broken grub as Windows is then first in boot order. But Windows often does other updates. It may turn its fast start up or other settings back to defaults. Windows & now Linux with fwupdate can also update UEFI. A UEFI update may also change settings to defaults. Windows often turns UEFI Secure boot on. UEFI Fast boot may get turned on making it more difficult to access a key to make changes. A lot depends on UEFI's implementation which varies greatly by vendor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does it wipe EFI partition?

It does not.

> Does it remove non-Windows stuff from EFI partition?

Negative.

> Maybe something else?

It may or may not overwrite `EFI/Boot/BOOTX64.EFI` - but that normally happens only during installation or an update from e.g. Windows 10 to Windows 11. I've not heard of this file being overwritten during Windows updates but it can probably happen. This is the default boot loader in many cases which can result in Linux boot failing.

> I know for a fact that rEFInd basically have its own folder in EFI partition

This is normally how OSes should install their bootloaders along with adding an entry to the EFI boot table (a special structure, see `man efibootmgr`).

> This means that rEFInd is more clear than GRUB (I remember GRUB also stores some files in /boot/ directory of a distro).

rEFInd is certainly more versatile. Many distros are yet to employ [Boot Loader Specification](https://uapi-group.org/specifications/specs/boot_loader_specification/) so they require a grub.cfg file to be booted.

> But I think it doesn't solve the "Windows update broke my GRUB (rEFInd)" problem. Or does it?

Even if Windows overwrites `EFI/Boot/BOOTX64.EFI` your EFI should still contain entires for other boot loaders. And even without these entires you can manually load `EFI/refind/refind_x64.efi`.

Comment: Are `BOOTX64.EFI` file and 1st UEFI boot entry the same thing? Or the file is just a fallback option (as far as I found out) and each UEFI boot entry is an existing .efi file in EFI partition (which means that UEFI directly executes `EFI/refind/refind_x64.efi` during system boot, bypassing `EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI`)?

Comment: *Are BOOTX64.EFI file and 1st UEFI boot entry the same thing?* No. `BOOTX64.EFI` is the default when nothing is yet written to the EFI boot table. The EFI boot table is able to set any entry as default, but when the table is not yet populated, `EFI/Boot/BOOTX64.EFI` will be executed automatically. Think of it as a default entry which can be overridden.